# Rails modules conflict with model class names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In our Rails app we have some models like:

```
module ProductName
  class StoreBuild
  end
end
```

And then we have some workers like:

```
module ProductName
  module StoreBuild
    class StoreBuildWorker
    end
  end
end
```

We then call these workers like:

```
ProductName::StoreBuild::StoreBuildWorker.perform_async(@store_build.id)
```

However we sometimes have encountered an error:

```
TypeError:
  StoreBuild is not a module
```

When we inspect the StoreBuild from that last line it, it thinks it's the model class and not the worker module we are referencing which is causing the error...

How do you stop modules conflicting with class names?

Annoyingly Rails doesn't use namespaces for top-level folders so it means Models and Workers that want to use the same namespaces conflict because they don't have any namespaces themselves.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that because they are both in the same namespace you can't give them same name. Try changing the module name from `StoreBuild` to something else. it should solve your problem. would share more docs for this.

Answer (score 3):

This is failing due to Rails' autoloading hierarchy. Brush up on [Autoloading and Reloading Constants](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) to see how this works.

Rails sees `ProductName::StoreBuild`, and then caches its reference as a class and not a  module. When you then have `ProductName::StoreBuild::StoreBuildWorker`, it says "huh, it's a module now" and freaks out.

Anecdotal: your app is probably very-well organized.

Comment: So are we saying you can't have a module and model with the same name under the same module?

Comment: No. Rails only wants one kind of name per thing (module, class). Usually what I do is pluralize for modules with similar names, such as `ProductName::StoreBuild::StoreBuildWorker` would become `ProductName::StoreBuilds::StoreBuildWorker`. It's not the prettiest, but it gets the point across.

Comment: @Cameron This is Ruby more than specifically rails. This is a naming conflict because a Module class is Module and a Class class is Class. If they were in different namespaces then this would be acceptable but no inside the same namespace. That being said nothing stops you from declaring `StoreBuildWorker` inside the class `StoreBuild`

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that there is a conflict since you are redefining `ProductName::StoreBuild` as a module where you have previously defined the same thing as a class.

If you don't want to rename anything, you can nest modules within a class if it makes sense in the namespacing of your app.

So if you have a class:

```rb
module ProductName
  class StoreBuild
  end
end
```

You can embed another class underneath it like so:

```rb
module ProductName
  class StoreBuild
    class StoreBuildWorker
    end
  end
end
```